# Send emails with Nodemailer and AWS SES with imports

Tags: amazon-web-services, nodemailer, amazon-ses

Although the official Nodemailer documentation explains [how to use Nodemailer with AWS SES](https://nodemailer.com/transports/ses/), the sample code uses `require` statements.

How to do the same with `import` statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nodemailer can be used with AWS SES with:

```js
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer'
import * as aws from '@aws-sdk/client-ses'

const ses = new aws.SES({
  apiVersion: "2010-12-01",
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  credentials: {
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  }
});

const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  SES: { ses, aws }
});

let info = await transporter.sendMail({
  from: '"Fred Foo " <foo@example.com>',
  to: "bar@example.com, baz@example.com",
  subject: "Hello ✔",
  text: "Hello world?",
  html: "<p>Hello world?</p>"
});
```

PS: The trick about the AWS `import` was originally posted as a [GH comment](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/1293#issuecomment-878031206).